# Have more than one BxSliders with customised nextSelector and prevSelector

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I have more than one bxSliders on a page that I want to control separately. The problem is that I don't know how to control their next and Previous selectors, as they'll be with the same name. Or so I think as I wanna control them separately without writing a separate function for their next and previous buttons.

How can I effectively do that with arrays so that I can control them individually without writing code for each one of them.

Here is what I am doing:-

```
var questionslider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({

        nextSelector: '#slider-next',
        prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
        nextText: 'Next Question',
        prevText: '←',
        pager: false,
        infiniteLoop: false,
        hideControlOnEnd: true

    });

    var questionslider2 = $('.bxslider2').bxSlider({

        nextSelector: '#slider-next',
        prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
        nextText: 'Next Question',
        prevText: '←',
        pager: false,
        infiniteLoop: false,
        hideControlOnEnd: true

    });
```

Here is how I am doing the NextSelector, I don't need the Previous button.

```
if ($('#slider-next a.bx-next').is(".disabled")) {

    $('#questions .continue').hide();
}
    else { $('#questions .continue').show(); }
```

Finally the HTML is:-

```
         <li class="question">
                <div class="overview">
                <h2>Title goes here</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec hendrerit ligula. Ut non justo in massa bibendum rutrum ac eu massa. Pellentesque in arcu dui. Nulla sollicitudin dui sed commodo congue. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus ante neque, scelerisque et adipiscing sit amet, hendrerit tempus magna. Ut vel eros in sapien condimentum sodales at gravida velit. Nullam dolor enim, lobortis nec hendrerit eget, vulputate sit amet eros. Quisque varius, ligula sed luctus pretium, justo sem interdum nunc, suscipit accumsan velit nunc eget nibh. Nunc justo leo, dignissim ac est ut, lacinia dictum nulla. Nullam odio nibh, faucibus sed felis nec, interdum ornare nulla.</p> 
                </div>

                <img src="images/a-laptop-1.png" class="laptop">

                <div class="q">

                    <ul class="bxslider question-slide">

                        <li>

                            <p>1. Nullam odio nibh, faucibus sed felis nec, interdum ornare nulla?</p>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#"><span>A.</span> 1/4</a><span class="extra">X.1%</span></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span>B.</span> 1/2</a><span class="extra">X.7%</span></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span>C.</span> 1/3</a><span class="extra">X.4%</span></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="correct"><span>D.</span> 2/3</a><span class="extra">X.1%</span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li>

                            <p>2. Nullam odio nibh, faucibus sed felis nec, interdum ornare nulla?</p>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#"><span>A.</span> 1/4</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span>B.</span> 1/2</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span>C.</span> 1/3</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="correct"><span>D.</span> 2/3</a><span class="extra">X.x%</span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                    <div class="continue">
                      <p><span id="slider-next"></span></p>
                    </div>
            </div>


        </li>

        <li class="question">
                <div class="overview">
                <h2>Title goes here</h2>
                    <p>Quisque nec hendrerit ligula. Ut non justo in massa bibendum rutrum ac eu massa. Pellentesque in arcu dui. Nulla sollicitudin dui sed commodo congue. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus ante neque, scelerisque et adipiscing sit amet, hendrerit tempus magna. Ut vel eros in sapien condimentum sodales at gravida velit. Nullam dolor enim, lobortis nec hendrerit eget, vulputate sit amet eros. Quisque varius.</p> 
                </div>

                <img src="images/laptop-1.png" class="laptop">

                <div class="q">

                    <ul class="bxslider2 question-slide">

                        <li>

                            <p>1. Nullam odio nibh, faucibus sed felis nec, interdum ornare nulla?</p>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#"><span>A.</span> 1/4</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span>B.</span> 1/2</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span>C.</span> 1/3</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="correct"><span>D.</span> 2/3</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li>

                            <p>2. Nullam odio nibh, faucibus sed felis nec, interdum ornare nulla??</p>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#"><span>A.</span> 1/4</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span>B.</span> 1/2</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span>C.</span> 1/3</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="correct"><span>D.</span> 2/3</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                    <div class="continue">
                      <p><span id="slider-next"></span></p>
                    </div>
            </div>


        </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply rename prev and next button of your second slider and then initialize it with they new name:

```
var questionslider2 = $('.bxslider2').bxSlider({

    nextSelector: '#slider-next2',
    prevSelector: '#slider-prev2',
    nextText: 'Next Question',
    prevText: '←',
    pager: false,
    infiniteLoop: false,
    hideControlOnEnd: true

});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/EbdJg/

### Example:

#### HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Examples | Responsive jQuery Slider | bxSlider</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="content slider, responsive image gallery, responsive image gallery, image slider, image fade, image rotator" />
        <meta name="description" content="Respsonsive jQuery content slider." />
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="25AuAMRK4hudMM4ZYCQnmQp9W9XtTtsutIDiZmKnjOo" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bxslider.com/css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bxslider.com/css/github.css" type="text/css" />

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->

        <script src="http://bxslider.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <script src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
        <script src="http://bxslider.com/js/rainbow.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://bxslider.com/js/scripts.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body class="example-item">



        <h1>Custom next / prev control selectors</h1>

        <div class="slider">
            <ul class="bxslider">
                <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/me_trees.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="outside">
                <h3>This div is outside of the slider</h3>
                <p><span id="slider-prev"></span> | <span id="slider-next"></span></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h1>Custom next / prev control selectors</h1>

        <div class="slider">
            <ul class="bxslider2">
                <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/me_trees.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="outside">
                <h3>This div is outside of the slider</h3>
                <p><span id="slider-prev2"></span> | <span id="slider-next2"></span></p>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        nextSelector: '#slider-next',
        prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
        nextText: 'Onward &rarr;',
        prevText: '&larr; Go back'
    });

    $('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
        nextSelector: '#slider-next2',
        prevSelector: '#slider-prev2',
        nextText: 'Onward &rarr;',
        prevText: '&larr; Go back'
    });    
});
```

Comment: The problem is that it is actually a questionnaire and if I keep on adding sliders, it just adds lots of redundant code. I was hoping I could do it through arrays and automate it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: To start with, how can I control the multiple Next and Previous Buttons even if I take your approach? Thanks.

Comment: Simply, every slider needs to have outside div as control holder. This code snippet should do it: if ($('.continue').find('#slider-next a.bx-next').is(".disabled")) {
    $('#questions .continue').hide();
}
else { $('#questions .continue').show(); }

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter how many navigation buttons you have.

Comment: Actually, the code you mentioned mixes up and it just ignores the second bxslider (bxslider2).

Comment: This should work:     $('.outside').find('.bx-next').each(function( index ) {
        if($(this).is(".disabled")) {
            $('#questions .continue').hide(); 
        }
    });

Comment: Plus shouldn't you use .hasClass(".disabled") instead of .is(".disabled")? Or if you are looking if element is disabled -> .is(":disabled")